# How to put 2 drop down menu and a search bar nect to each other using the CSS bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am currently using the [CSS bootstrap 3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment) in my application.

I am trying to place 2 drop down menu "with the arrow only- not button style" next to each other and then to the right I want to add a search bar.

I want to use the the [dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) menu that the bootstrap has but without the button style "arrow only" and a small search bar to the right in the vertical center.

I have tried to do that but the dropdown menus and the search bar do not line up.

here is a screenshot of what I have done
[image]

and here is my code

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">


      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle menu-sm-padding" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          My Name <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

        <li><a href="/user_profile.php">My Profile</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="/index.php?action=logout">Logout</a></li>      
        </ul>
      </li>




      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle menu-sm-padding" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          My Company Name <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"><li><a class="master_client_change" href="#" id="current_client_id_2">Comp 1</a></li><li><a class="master_client_change" href="#" id="current_client_id_1">Comp 2</a></li><li><a class="master_client_change" href="#" id="current_client_id_3">Comp 3</a></li><li><a class="master_client_change" href="#" id="current_client_id_6">Comp 4</a></li></ul>
      </li>

    </ul>

<div class="width-sm-size box-inline-block">
<form action="/accounts_search.php" method="get" id="searchforactivities" class="navbar-form navbar-right row-right-xxsm-margin" role="search">

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" name="search_term">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

How can I get the dropdown menu and the search bar to line up?
and is there a trick in making the search bar little fancy by making the the corners of the input round and the Go button a search icon?

Comment: Right click, inspect element, find out what the extra space is caused by

Comment: How can I tell what were is the extra space? I am on the inspect element screen

Comment: On chrome, when you've clicked inspect element and the developer tools are open, click the "styles" tab on the frame on the right, scroll to the bottom and there is a box-model diagram. If you hover on the various sections of the diagram it will illustrate them live on the page. I assume the process is similar for other browsers or developer tools

Comment: Perfect, got it! any idea on how to make the search bar a bit cooler? with round corner and change the button to an icon?

Comment: Well to change the button to an icon, remove the text "Go" and replace it with `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>` or whichever icon you want. Then to add border radius to the input just add `input[type="search"] { border-radius: 6px }` to your CSS. Obviously these are just examples, but a comment convo isn't the best way to show someone these things :P